# Using scikit learn to predict good content on a website

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction

I have a year's worth of data from a website. I would like to train a machine learning algorithm to predict the success of new content based on certain variables (e.g.,number of words, time of day of posting, etc.)

I would like to take a new piece of data, input certain characteristics about it, and receive a probability for how well it will do on the site.

Further, I would like to continue to add future data to the training set and continually train the algorithm to get smarter over time.

My question is: How should I go about using scikit-learn to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

What you have is a binary classification problem, ie you have to decide if a given input is good or not.

Try different regression algorithms, scikits-learn makes it super easy to switch algorithms, allowing you to see what works and what doesn't.

From the top of my head, here are some methods I'd try:

- SVM
- Random forests (Forest of randomized trees in scikits)
- Regression (Ridge, Lasso, IRLS, logistic)
- Naive Bayes
- k nearest neighbors

How to assess the quality of a given method? Use cross validation (do it 10 fold if you have enough data and 5 fold otherwise). There's a full section (5.1) of the scikits-learn manual dedicated to this.

Adding new data to the training set will require to retrain your model. Depending on the computing power you have at hand it may or may not be a problem. If you have a lot of examples, adding one won't change much, so be sure to re-train your algorithm with a handful of new examples. That will save computational time.

Algorithm that uses training sets are called offline algorithms. On the other hand, online algorithms learn every time they are presented a new example. If you actually need this, try online methods, like k nearest neighbors.

If you need example code, scikit-learn doc is very helpful:
- http://scikit-learn.org/0.10/auto_examples/linear_model/logistic_l1_l2_sparsity.html#example-linear-model-logistic-l1-l2-sparsity-py
- http://scikit-learn.org/0.10/modules/linear_model.html#ridge-regression

http://scikit-learn.org/0.10/user_guide.html

Comment: Rather than reading the documentation for 0.10 you should read the latest stable doc at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/ or the doc for the dev version if you build scikit-learn from the master branch hosted on github: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/